# Getting warnings when running Appium-doctor

Tags: appium

Upon opening the terminal(cmd), running appium-doctor, I'm getting following warnings:

```
WARN AppiumDoctor ✖ opencv4nodejs cannot be found.
WARN AppiumDoctor ✖ fbsimctl cannot be found 
WARN AppiumDoctor ✖ applesimutils cannot be found
```

Any Idea what is the root cause of this and How can I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 5):

Installed cmake through terminal
brew install cmake

and installed opencv4nodejs by

npm i -g opencv4nodejs

now one warning - WARN AppiumDoctor ✖ opencv4nodejs cannot be found fixed.

Comment: this was helpful to fix the missing `opencv4nodejs`

Comment: This is not longer working, after installing cmake and running `npm i -g opencv4node.js` I got some errors 
--> 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./install/install.js
npm ERR! info install using lib dir: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR! /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37
...

Answer (score 5):

I hope the following commands can help you:

```
brew tap wix/brew
brew install applesimutils
```

Answer (score 1):

For WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ fbsimctl cannot be found

## Get the Facebook Tap.

brew tap facebook/fb

## Install fbsimctl from master

brew install fbsimctl --HEAD

WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ applesimutils cannot be found

brew tap wix/brew
brew install wix/brew/applesimutils

Comment: didn't fix `✖ applesimutils cannot be found` for me.